# What is the method to cache results using JPA when queried by a non-primary key?

Tags: jpa, caching, eclipselink, query-cache

I have a JPA entity `EntityA` mapped to a table `TABLE_A` with data like:

`OBJ_ID | REF_ID | STATUS | ...` where `OBJ_ID` is the primary key and `REF_ID` is a foreign key from another table `TABLE_B` which is not managed by JPA.

I need to be able to:

1. Return all rows which relate to a given value of a non-primary key, say `REF_ID`:

   `SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE REF_ID = 'REF_ID_1'`
2. Cache results from (1), so I do not hit the database until a write has been performed.
3. During write (UPDATE / DELETE) within a transaction, read back all rows including un-committed data as in (1):

Code:

```
fetchAllByRefId('REF_ID_1');
// Fires: SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE REF_ID = 'REF_ID_1'
// Let's assume this returns 1 row

Transaction {
    update('REF_ID_1', 'REF_ID_2');
    // Fires: UPDATE TABLE_A SET REF_ID = 'REF_ID_2' WHERE REF_ID = 'REF_ID_1'
    fetchAllByRefId('REF_ID_1');
    // Fires: SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE REF_ID = 'REF_ID_1'
    // This should return 0 rows
}

fetchAllByRefId('REF_ID_1');
// Fires: SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE REF_ID = 'REF_ID_1'
// If the transaction gets committed, this should return 0 rows
// If rolled back, should return 1 row
```

I tried to use Eclipselink's implementation of JPA to map the entity against `TABLE_A`.
I am using the object (L2) cache to cache by primary key, and using the query cache to cache results queried by a non-primary key field such as `REF_ID` or `STATUS`.

From the [documentation of Query Results cache](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/concepts/cache008.htm#CDEBGAHD):

> The query results cache does not pick up committed changes from the
> application as the object cache does. It should only be used to cache
> read-only objects, or should use an invalidation policy to avoid
> caching stale results. Committed changes to the objects in the result
> set will still be picked up, but changes that affect the results set
> (such as new or changed objects that should be added/removed from the
> result set) will not be picked up.

Further, if the query cache is not the correct thing to use for caching the results, what is the way to cache results fetched by a non-primary key field?

I was not able to find an equivalent to Spring Data's `findAll(Example<S>)` where I can specify a predicate, in the `EntityManager` API - everything seems to require the primary key. I have tried `CriteriaQuery`, but was unable to cache its results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query cache, as the doc states, is a query result cache storing the results the database returned. These results are not entities so they aren't maintained within a UnitOfWork or EntityManager context; once read in, they are unchanged until they are cleared. That isn't to say you will get stale data back; there is a separate entity cache that still gets used that you may need to configure (it is on by default). What that means is that if you execute a `SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE REF_ID = 'REF_ID_1'` query, it will cache and return the rows that match up instead of hitting the database, but use the Entity cache to return the entity objects. So it will return all TableA instances that had a Ref_id = 'REF_ID_1' as of the time the query was cached, but if the entities exist in the entity cache, may show a different ref_id as well as any other state that might have since changed. This would also mean it might exclude new instances or include deleted ones if the query result is very stale; as of [EclipseLink 2.5](http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2013/06/cool-performance-features-of.html), EclipseLink can invalidate query cache results based on the changes involved, which will cause your query to refresh from the database on the next execution.

Your issue though seems to be with how query caches must be used. EclipseLink only supports query caches through named queries. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72233667/496099) for details on how to add named queries. In Spring, they are looked up using the method name first before it tries to generate a query.

So a `"TableA.fetchAllByRefId"` named query would get used on a TableARepository class method:

```
List<TableA> fetchAllByRefId(@Param("REF_ID") String refId);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am indeed using the entity (L2) cache (as mentioned in the question), but it works *only with primary keys*, hence I am unable to cache entities when I query using a non-primary key column. However, I am interested in the configuration to "invalidate query cache results based on the changes involved" - could you please point me to that? Thanks again!

Comment: as far as I'm aware, it is automatically done with the only config needed is to turn on the query cache. The query cache is for named queries. I just figured you seemed specifically aimed at the query cache and it would suit your use case but it isn't quite true that the cache is only for primary keys. You can use EclipseLInk's CacheIndex annotation https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_cacheindex.htm but only if the field is unique like an ID would be. I'm not certain this will be a good fit, where as named queries for the fk should fit more situations.

Comment: Thanks @Chris! one of the reasons I moved on from CacheIndex was that (according to the documentation: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/concepts/cache006.htm) it works only for single result queries (2.4 doc says: "A resultList query cannot obtain cache hits, as it is unknown if all of the objects are in memory"; 2.7 doc says: "Only single results can be obtained from indexed queries"). Is there a configuration or control to expand this to list results (OneToMany / ManyToMany relationships)?

Comment: Also, for invalidation, I have it enabled (as in default), but that still retains the cache until the transaction is committed, hence the fetchAllByRefId('REF_ID_1') within the transaction returns me 1 row. Is there a way to make the query cache transaction aware like the L2 cache is? I have tried using the JpaCache API to force invalidate the query cache within the transaction, but not sure if that is a good way to do this.

Comment: CacheIndex: no, as that isn't its purpose. Cache index functions as an extra index overtop of the entity cache, so functions the same way an ID cache/index does. An alternate or natural PK vs the entity/JPA designated ID lookup. It would also help when referencing a non-ID field, but only for 1:1 lookups. Query cache is the way to go for others. As to invalidation 'inside' a unit of work; try calling flush, but I don't think the query cache attempts to isolate data from other queries in other UOW/EMs. Could be a feature to add. You'll have to bypass the cache after making changes.

Comment: The flush did not work for me. The query cache still seems to hold on to stale values. In your answer, you pointed to a blog on eclipse 2.5's invalidation of query cache when a new entity gets added or deleted: problem is, this does not seem to work when I am in a transaction.

Comment: "In EclipseLink 2.5 automatic invalidation of the query cache was added. So if you had a query "Select e from Employee e" and had enabled query caching, every execution of this query would hit the cache and avoid accessing the database. Then if you inserted a new Employee, in EclipseLink 2.5 the query cache for all queries for Employee will automatically get invalidated. The next query will access the database, and get the correct result, and update the cache so all subsequent queries will once again obtain cache hits." - this is the section I am alluding to.

Comment: I thought I was clear that I didn't think it would work. Query caches are outside of transactions; they can be seen and are shared by by all processes using that persistence unit. So they are not allowed to cache uncommitted changes. Invalidation of these caches is done after the transaction commits, when shared caches are updated (or invalidated), as there is no point invalidating it on a flush; out side processes would just reload the soon to be stale data back into it. This will only work when you commit a transaction; you'll have to bypass the cache for specific transactional changes

Comment: Much thanks, Chris! So, by bypassing the cache, do you mean overriding the Query hint to go directly against the database? Or is there a different way to do this within a transaction?

Comment: yes; if you think your context contains changes that might affect the query, you'll have to add/remove hints to turn the query cache off for that query - and be sure to flush the context as well - manually. Also mentioned, what you need would make a great feature. Someone might be able to contribute or add an EM local query cache, or one that is aware of changes discovered in flush operations so that it bypasses the query cache automatically for you.