# What is the technique to configure JPA query cache so that it avoids multiple database hits when query returns no results?

Tags: jpa, caching, eclipselink, query-cache

I am using EclipseLink's implementation of JPA to query a table *using a non-primary key field*.

To cache results returned by this query, I have configured Query Results cache.

I have also annotated my entity with QUERY_RESULTS_CACHE_IGNORE_NULL set to true, so that it allows insert of new rows as per [this javadoc](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.7/org/eclipse/persistence/config/QueryHints.html#QUERY_RESULTS_CACHE_IGNORE_NULL).

However, when no results are returned, firing the query misses the cache.
Is there a configuration on query results cache either in JPA or Eclipselink which causes a cache hit even when no results are returned?

This behavior seems to be conflicting with the QUERY_RESULTS_CACHE_IGNORE_NULL flag. I expect the cache to be flushed once there is a subsequent write, followed by the query being fired again.

Comment: The QUERY_RESULTS_CACHE_IGNORE_NULL description states it causes nulls to not be cached. When a query returns no values, this means it is null and so not cached. Did you try leaving it false? What difference does it make to new objects and secondary key indexing in your application?

Comment: You might want to try the CACHE Usage query hint: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/config/QueryHints.html#CACHE_USAGE . This will have it return no results if there isn't anything that matches in the cache, and you'll have to configure or determine your own mechanisms to ensure that is really what you want: without a cache of null values, there is no way to verify a database miss and treat it differently from a cache miss, so it is up to you to decide if/when to hit the database with such queries.

Comment: When I try leaving QUERY_RESULTS_CACHE_IGNORE_NULL to false (default), I have a single hit to the database for the non-primary key query, but then I am back to the problem of invalidation in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72260226/what-is-the-method-to-cache-results-using-jpa-when-queried-by-a-non-primary-key/72262395 . New objects or deleted objects are not reflected.

Comment: Also, for clarity, I have tried separately using: CacheUsage.CheckCacheThenDatabase and CacheUsage.ConformResultsInUnitOfWork as hints, but I do not see any change in behavior, the results are still stale as fetched from the query result cache.